# Create user prompt and simulate interaction

Tags: java, scala

I have the following code(which I've simplified for the purpose of the question):

```
  def openFile(directory: File): Try[String] = {
      var input = ""
      do {
        input = readLine("prompt>")
        println("alibaba.txt: 100%")
      } while(input != ":quit")
   }
```

The workflow is this:

the user gets a prompt:

`prompt>`

The user writes `alibaba` and then presses enter

The user sees:

```
alibaba.txt: 100%
prompt>
```

Everything:

```
prompt>alibaba
alibaba.txt: 100%
prompt>
```

Now, I want to test it.

I wrote the following code to test the user interaction:

```
  test("simulate user input from readline") {
    val prompt = new Prompt()
    prompt.openFile(new File("../resources"))

    val in = new ByteArrayInputStream("alibaba\n".getBytes)
    System.setIn(in)

    val scanner: Scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
    val programResponse: String = scanner.nextLine()
    println("programResponse: " + programResponse)

    System.setIn(System.in)
    assert(programResponse == "alibaba.txt: 100%")
  }
```

However, I'm getting this result and I'm confused:

```
"alibaba[]" did not equal "alibaba[.txt: 100%]"
```

So how can I make the test simulate the user interaction?

How can I read what my program wrote?

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should structure your code in a way that it is simply testable meaning that you should extract IO to higher abstractions.

For demonstration purpose I slightly modified your example to the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner

object YourObject {

  def consoleMethod(in: () => String = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine,
                    out: String => Unit = System.out.println): Unit = {
    var input = ""
    do {
      out("prompt>")
      input = in()
      out("alibaba.txt: 100%")
    } while (input != ":quit")
  }
}
```

**Let's break it down**:

- `in: () => String = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine` stands for our source of the user input. By default it is `System.in`.
- `out: String => Unit = System.out.println` stands for our output source. By default it is `System.out`

Let's test the scenario when user entered `":quit"` right away:

```
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class Test extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  "We" should {
    "simulate user input from readline" in {
      var outputs = List.empty[String]
      def accumulate(output: String): Unit = outputs = outputs :+ output

      val in: () => String = () => ":quit"
      val out: String => Unit = accumulate _

      YourObject.consoleMethod(in, out)

      outputs shouldBe List("prompt>", "alibaba.txt: 100%")
    }
  }
}
```

---

In case you want more control you can use `scalamock`:

In this case we can **mock** out `in` and `out` to behave as we need them to do.

```
val in = mock[() => String]
val out = mock[String => Unit]
```

Setting up source expectations:

```
(in.apply _).expects().anyNumberOfTimes().onCall(_ => ":quit")
```

Now we want to set up `out` to record whatever we are going to write:

```
var outputs = List.empty[String]
def accumulate(output: String): Unit = outputs = outputs :+ output

(out.apply _)
  .expects(new FunctionAdapter1[String, Boolean](_ => true))
  .anyNumberOfTimes()
  .onCall(accumulate _)
```

Perfect, now let's set up the expectations:

```
outputs shouldBe List("prompt>", "alibaba.txt: 100%")
```

**Full source code of the test**:

```
import org.scalamock.function.FunctionAdapter1
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class Test extends WordSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {

  "We" should {
    "simulate user input from readline" in {
      val in = mock[() => String]
      val out = mock[String => Unit]

      (in.apply _).expects().anyNumberOfTimes().onCall(_ => ":quit")

      var outputs = List.empty[String]

      def accumulate(output: String): Unit = outputs = outputs :+ output

      (out.apply _)
        .expects(new FunctionAdapter1[String, Boolean](_ => true))
        .anyNumberOfTimes()
        .onCall(accumulate _)

      YourObject.consoleMethod(in, out)

      outputs shouldBe List("prompt>", "alibaba.txt: 100%")
    }
  }
}
```