# How to override stdin to a String

Tags: scala, stdin

Basic question, I want to set the standard input to be a specific string. Currently I am trying it with this:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
// Let's say we are inside a method now
val str = "textinputgoeshere"
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
```

Because that's similar to how I'd do it in Java, however str.getBytes seems to work differently in Scala as System in is set to a memory address when I check it with println....

I've looked at the Scala API: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Console$.html#setIn(in:java.io.InputStream):Unit
and I've found

```
def withIn[T](in: InputStream)(thunk: ⇒ T): T
```

But this seems to only set the input stream for a specific chunk of code, I'd like this to be a feature in a Setup method in my JUnit tests.

Comment: Scala has a slight dislike of sideeffects, and this one is a rather brutal one - could you also pass in the input stream into the method you're testing?

Comment: Looks like duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40344117/create-user-prompt-and-simulate-interaction/40350178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem ended up being something related to my code, not this specific concept. The correct way to override Standard In / System In to a String in Scala is the following:

```
val str = "your string here"
val in: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
Console.withIn(in)(yourMethod())"
```

My tests run correctly now.

Comment: Also this topic is covered 
in [the official scala.Console docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Console$.html)
where one can use 
java.io.StringReader as input source
`val input = new StringReader(s"${customStrInput}\n")`
or file content
`val input: Reader = openFile( "file.txt" )`
for `Console.withIn( input ) { ... }`